# Two forms of same class on one page in flask-wtforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

In my website, I have a model Experiment that contains many Activities. I have a view where people can add or remove Activities from an Experiment.

I show a table with Activities that are a part of this Experiment, and a table of Activities not a part of this Experiment. Users can check which Activities they want to add or remove and use a submit button under the table.

However, when I update the list of choices on one form, the list of choices on the other form reflects this. Am I doing something wrong?

For both adding and removing the Activities to/from the Experiment, I use the same form.

```
class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = CheckboxInput()

class ActivityListForm(Form):
    activities = MultiCheckboxField(validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")

    def populate_activities(self, activities_set):
        activities_mapping = {}
        for activity in activities_set:
            activities_mapping[str(activity.id)] = activity
            choice_tuple = (str(activity.id), activity.question)
            self.activities.choices.append(choice_tuple)
        return activities_mapping
```

Here is my view:

```
def settings_experiment(exp_id):
    experiment = Experiment.query.get(exp_id)

    remove_activities_form = ActivityListForm(prefix="remove")
    add_activities_form = ActivityListForm(prefix="add")

    remove_activities_mapping = remove_activities_form.populate_activities(
        experiment.activities)

    add_activities_mapping = add_activities_form.populate_activities(
        Activity.query.\
            filter(not_(Activity.experiments.any(id=experiment.id))).all())


    return render_template("experiments/settings_experiment.html",
                           experiment=experiment,
                           update_experiment_form=update_experiment_form,
                           remove_activities_form=remove_activities_form,
                           add_activities_form=add_activities_form,
                           add_activities_mapping=add_activities_mapping,
                           remove_activities_mapping=remove_activities_mapping)
```

Although `remove_activities_form` and `add_activities_form` have their options set separately to different lists, they both end up containing a union of their two option lists, which messes up my template rendering. Is there a way to keep them separate or am I screwed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/284

Solution in the above discussion.